# Intellij GIT reset unpushed commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ for a project after some time. I committed time ago something (but not pushed them), and now I would like to commit something else, but when I go on the tab Git -> Push... I found a list of unpushed commits that I don't want to push anymore. How can I "abort" those commits, to commit my new stuff?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I undo pushed commits using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/how-can-i-undo-pushed-commits-using-git)

Comment: this is purely git. Your preference of ide is not relevant for this.

Comment: @Stultuske sadly not because my commits are still not pushed, they're just in the push queue

Comment: ok, then it's this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197413/how-do-i-delete-unpushed-git-commits

Comment: @Stultuske It doesn't work, if I go in the tab Git -> Push I still have the list of unpunshed commits that I don't want

Comment: @Stultuske If the OP is trying to find out how to do this in IntelliJ, it is not purely about Git, but about the GUI of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options in IntelliJ to reset unpushed commits:

1. [Reset a branch to a specific commit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/undo-changes.html#reset-HEAD)
2. [Drop commit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/undo-changes.html#afbda31d)